# Does the ring extension $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{10}]$ satisfy the going up property?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Does the ring extension $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{10}]$ satisfy the going up property?

**Going up property:** For a ring extension $A\subset B$, if for any prime ideals $p\subset p'$ of $A$ and prime ideal $P$ in $B$ that lies over $p$, there is a prime ideal $P'$ in $B$ such that $P\subset P'$ and $P'$ lies over $p'$.

I know that a chain of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ is:

$$(0)\subset (p)$$ for primes $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and a chain of prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{10}]$ is:

$$(0)\subset (p)$$ for $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ except $p=2,5$.

Then clearly the going up property is satisfied for chains where $p\neq 2,5$. But I am confused if it has to also hold for the other chains as well. In other words, the going up property is said to be satisfied if it holds for all chains of prime ideals?

Could someone kindly clarify this?

Comment: Please edit your post to recall the definition of the going up property. I think the answer will then become obvious.

Comment: @AnneBauval So, the answer is that the ring extension does satisfy the going up property, right?

Comment: What is the reasoning which led you to this conclusion?

Comment: @AnneBauval I think I am a bit confused over the "any" before prime ideals in the definition. Could you kindly clarify this?

Comment: The "for any" means "for every" ... (such that ...). Formally: $\forall$

Comment: @AnneBauval Understood. Thank you for helping!

Comment: For the chain of prime ideals $(0)\subset (2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ there is no prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{10}]$ that lies over $(2)$, so this implies that the going up property is not satisfied.

Comment: I think the same.